# How to save Scrapy crawl Command output

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to save the output of the scrapy crawl command I have tried 
`scrapy crawl someSpider -o some.json -t json >> some.text`
But it doesn't worked ...can some body tell me how i can save output to a text file....I mean the logs and information printed by scrapy...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to redirect stderr too. You are redirecting only stdout.
You can redirect it somehow like this:

`scrapy crawl someSpider -o some.json -t json 2> some.text`

The key is number 2, which "selects" stderr as source for redirection.

If you would like to redirect both stderr and stdout into one file, you can use:

`scrapy crawl someSpider -o some.json -t json &> some.text`

For more about output redirection:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Answer (score 45):

You can add these lines to your `settings.py`:

```
LOG_STDOUT = True
LOG_FILE = '/tmp/scrapy_output.txt'
```

And then start your crawl normally:

```
scrapy crawl someSpider
```

Comment: Check [link](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#logging-settings) for more logging settings. You can even use `scrapy crawl MyCrawler -s LOG_FILE=/var/log/crawler_mycrawler.log` -s trigger to change crawler settings on the fly.

Answer (score 9):

For all `scrapy` commands you can add `--logfile NAME_OF_FILE` to log to a file e.g.

```
scrapy crawl someSpider -o some.json --logfile some.text
```

There are two other useful command line options for logging:

- `-L` or `--loglevel` to control the logging level e.g. `-L INFO` (the default is `DEBUG`)
- `--nolog` to disable logging completely

These commands are [documented here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#command-line-options).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the output from runspider command.

```
scrapy runspider scraper.py -o some.json -t json 2> some.text
```

This works as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `nohup`:

```
nohup scrapy crawl someSpider &
```

The log will be stored in nohup.out

Answer (score 0):

You can save as log file:

```
scrapy crawl someSpider -s LOG_FILE=fileName.log -L <loglevel>
```

**loglevel** can be one between `CRITICAL`, `ERROR`, `WARNING`, `INFO` and `DEBUG` or `--nolog` for no log. for more information read [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
scrapy crawl someSpider --logfile some.text
```

This will do exactly what you are looking for, save the output of the command that you see on the screen to a text file.