# writing scrapy logs into a file

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy spider with `LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'`,How can I write the log message that appear (while spider is running) into a simple text file instead of reading them directly from terminal.

Note: I also tried to copy&paste the log on terminal into a text file but because the spider scrapes many pages the terminal doesn't show all

My question is basically How can I directly write what scrapy shows on terminal directly into a file so I can view later on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save Scrapy crawl Command output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650397/how-to-save-scrapy-crawl-command-output)

Answer (score 1):

Add `--logfile my_logfile.txt` to your `scrapy` command e.g. from tutorial

```
scrapy runspider quotes_spider.py -o quotes.json --logfile my_log.log
```

Please read the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='log.txt',
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)
```

refer this https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html