# Why doesn't the output of a webpage in my browser match the page source code I get by scraping that webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written the following Scrapy spider in order to scrape the remote jobs available at StackOverflow Jobs:

```
import scrapy

class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jobs"
    start_urls = [
        "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote-developer-jobs"
    ]
    already_visited_links = []

    def parse(self, response, page_number=0): # 0 is a magic number for an invalid page number
        jobs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'job')]")
        links_to_next_pages = response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 's-pagination--item')]").css("a::attr(href)").getall()

        # visit each job page (as I do in the browser) and scrape the relevant information (Job title etc.)
        for job in jobs:
            # get the id of the job
            job_id = int(job.xpath('@data-jobid').extract_first()) 
            if page_number != 0:
                job_link_to_visit = "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?id=" + str(job_id) + "&r=true" + "&p=" + str(page_number)
            else:
                job_link_to_visit = "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?id=" + str(job_id) + "&r=true"
            request = scrapy.Request(job_link_to_visit,
                             callback=self.parse_job)
            yield request

        # go to the next job listings page (if you haven't already been there)
        for link_to_next_page in links_to_next_pages:
            if link_to_next_page not in self.already_visited_links:
                self.already_visited_links.append(link_to_next_page)
                next_page_number = 0
                # below is a pattern I noticed: whenever a link has a p in its GET request, it is always near the end
                # therefore, here I check if the last thing in the link is "p=<someNumber>" and if it is
                # then I get <someNumber>; I know this is not robust, but I currently can't think of a better way to do this
                if link_to_next_page[-4] == "p":
                    next_page_number = int(link_to_next_page[-1])
                if link_to_next_page[-5] == "p":
                    next_page_number = int(link_to_next_page[-2:])
                print("next_page_number")
                print(next_page_number)
                yield response.follow(link_to_next_page, callback=self.parse, cb_kwargs={"page_number" : next_page_number})

        print("End of parse method")

    def parse_job(self, response):
        with open("dump.txt", "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Now here's what bothers me. The spider output when the `parse_job` method gets called is:

```
2021-04-30 19:46:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?id=522636&r=true> (referer: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote-developer-jobs)
```

When I manually go to the link `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?id=522636&r=true` I get a job with the title *Senior Backend Engineer, Payments*. However, when I open the `dump.txt` file my spider generated, and search for that string, it doesn't find anything! Clearly, my spider is not getting the content I see in my browser.

Can someone tell me what to do? From Googling around I can speculate that I'm dealing with some JavaScript stuff here. **How can I specifically scrape the contents of each Stack Overflow remote job details page (making it as though I clicked on it in the browser)?** What I want to get on each job page is the job title, salary (if provided), job type, experience level, role, industry, company size, company type, preferred timezone and technologies.

Comment: Just to note: you don't have to write code to save the output to a file. When you run the spider, you can save the output (e.g. the yielded items) by using the `-o` flag. E.g. `scrapy crawl jobs -o dumps.txt` (or more appropriately: `jobs.json`). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650397/how-to-save-scrapy-crawl-command-output

Comment: Also, you probably want to link directly to the job listing (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/522636/senior-backend-engineer-payments-spotify). Linking to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/522636/ will automatically redirect to the former.

Comment: @zmike Even when I link directly to the job listing (as you indicated in your 2nd comment), I still don't get the same result in the scraper as I do in the web browser. My problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to fetch a list of direct links from https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote-developer-jobs (or similar links). You will then get a list of links that are like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/522636/senior-backend-engineer-payments-spotify.

The direct link to the job ad will have the following script element in the HTML source code. This will be there even if the JavaScript isn't there.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"JobPosting","title":"Senior Backend Engineer, Payments","skills":["python","java","payment"],"description":"<h2>About this job</h2>\r\n<p><span>Location options: <strong>Remote</strong></span><br/><span>Job type: <strong>Full-time</strong></span><br/><span>Experience level: <strong>Senior</strong></span><br/><span>Role: <strong>Backend Developer</strong></span><br/><span>Industry: <strong>Media, Music, podcasts</strong></span><br/><span>Company size: <strong>5k–10k people</strong></span><br/><span>Company type: <strong>Public</strong></span><br/></p><br/><br/><h2>Technologies</h2> <p>python, java, payment</p> <br/><br/><h2>Job description</h2> The Money Product Area is responsible for enabling payment services to the whole of Spotify, from taking a regular Spotify subscription payment to e.g. a business ad sales payment. Today we are looking for a Senior Backend Engineer to join the Scrooge squad, and be part of the Money product area which covers all payments functions such as Risk &amp; Fraud, Checkout service and Alternative payment methods.\r\n\r\nScrooge is at the core of all payment transactions at Spotify, our main function is to process payment transactions with Payment processors or other internal payment functions. In this role in Scrooge, you will have unique and challenging opportunities to implement change in a complex high volume system environment where many things change the whole time, the tech stack, PSPs, regulations, new payment functionalities, etc. The list is long. You will together with the other ten members in the squad maintain and develop the Python code running in GCP and save all transactions in a Postgres database.\r\n\r\nThe squad is in close cooperation with many stakeholders, of course the business team who strive for high auth rates and low transaction cost, surrounding sister teams inside the Money Product Area as well as in the larger Spotify. As Money is a central piece we are part of all company wide initiatives which includes payments.  You will assume a lot of responsibility and it will be exciting moments when we deploy structural changes that affect many or even all of our transactions, or when you are on-call and an incident occurs. \r\n\r\n\r\n<p><strong>What you&rsquo;ll do</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Be a valued member of an autonomous, cross-functional agile team</li>\r\n<li>Design, develop and maintain backend services with a focus on high availability, low latency and scalability.</li>\r\n<li>Take operational responsibility for the services that are owned by your team, including taking part in an on-call rotation</li>\r\n<li>Work closely with operations and compliance teams to make sure that you collaboratively provide for the company&rsquo;s short- and long-term goals, differentiating between building what is asked for and what is truly needed in the payments domain.</li>\r\n<li>Maintain and update our PCI environment</li>\r\n<li>Hack on what you want during regular system hack days and bi-annual hack weeks.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n<p><strong>Who you are</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>You are an awesome engineer working with scalable distributed systems that is more than comfortable writing Python (or Java) and working with Postgres.</li>\r\n<li>You know and care about sound engineering practices like continuous delivery and automated testing and have experience in working on cloud platforms like GCP / AWS.</li>\r\n<li>You are passionate about what you do and have a high interest in keeping up with current best practices in your areas of expertise</li>\r\n<li>Experience in working within the e-commerce, subscription or payments domain is a plus. </li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\nYou are welcome at Spotify for who you are, no matter where you come from, what you look like, or what&rsquo;s playing in your headphones. Our platform is for everyone, and so is our workplace. The more voices we have represented and amplified in our business, the more we will all thrive, contribute, and be forward-thinking! So bring us your personal experience, your perspectives, and your background. It&rsquo;s in our differences that we will find the power to keep revolutionizing the way the world listens.\r\n\r\nSpotify transformed music listening forever when we launched in 2008. Our mission is to unlock the potential of human creativity by giving a million creative artists the opportunity to live off their art and billions of fans the chance to enjoy and be passionate about these creators. Everything we do is driven by our love for music and podcasting. Today, we are the world&rsquo;s most popular audio streaming subscription service with a community of more than 345 million users. <br/><br/>","datePosted":"2021-04-30","validThrough":"2022-01-22","employmentType":"FULL_TIME","experienceRequirements":"Senior","industry":["Media","Music","podcasts"],"jobBenefits":["Incentive Mix Program","Parental Leave","Flexible Public Holidays","Spotify Premium Subscription","Trips & Festivals Around the Globe","Access to extensive learning opportunities for personal development","Travel insurance and additional support for all business trips","Free, confidential counseling sessions with a qualified counselor"],"hiringOrganization":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Spotify","sameAs":"http://www.spotifyjobs.com","logo":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYDzK.png","description":"<p>Our mission is to unlock the potential of human creativity&mdash;by giving a million creative artists the opportunity to live off their art and billions of fans the opportunity to enjoy and be inspired by it.</p>\r\n<p>Spotify transformed music listening forever when it launched in Sweden in 2008. Discover, manage and share over 50m tracks for free, or upgrade to Spotify Premium to access exclusive features including offline mode, improved sound quality, and an ad-free music listening experience.</p>\r\n<p>Today, Spotify is the most popular global audio streaming service with 286m users, including 130m subscribers across 79 markets. We are the largest driver of revenue to the music business today. </p>"},"jobLocationType":"TELECOMMUTE","applicantLocationRequirements":[{"@type":"Country","name":"SK"},{"@type":"Country","name":"PT"},{"@type":"Country","name":"RO"},{"@type":"Country","name":"SI"},{"@type":"Country","name":"SE"},{"@type":"Country","name":"PL"},{"@type":"Country","name":"NL"},{"@type":"Country","name":"NO"},{"@type":"Country","name":"MT"},{"@type":"Country","name":"LT"},{"@type":"Country","name":"LU"},{"@type":"Country","name":"LV"},{"@type":"Country","name":"FR"},{"@type":"Country","name":"GR"},{"@type":"Country","name":"HU"},{"@type":"Country","name":"HR"},{"@type":"Country","name":"IE"},{"@type":"Country","name":"IS"},{"@type":"Country","name":"IT"},{"@type":"Country","name":"EE"},{"@type":"Country","name":"DK"},{"@type":"Country","name":"CY"},{"@type":"Country","name":"CZ"},{"@type":"Country","name":"DE"},{"@type":"Country","name":"FI"},{"@type":"Country","name":"ES"},{"@type":"Country","name":"CH"},{"@type":"Country","name":"BE"},{"@type":"Country","name":"BG"},{"@type":"Country","name":"AT"},{"@type":"Country","name":"AD"},{"@type":"Country","name":"BA"},{"@type":"Country","name":"AX"},{"@type":"Country","name":"AL"},{"@type":"Country","name":"BY"},{"@type":"Country","name":"JE"},{"@type":"Country","name":"GI"},{"@type":"Country","name":"FO"},{"@type":"Country","name":"GB"},{"@type":"Country","name":"GG"},{"@type":"Country","name":"MC"},{"@type":"Country","name":"MD"},{"@type":"Country","name":"ME"},{"@type":"Country","name":"LI"},{"@type":"Country","name":"IM"},{"@type":"Country","name":"MK"},{"@type":"Country","name":"SJ"},{"@type":"Country","name":"RS"},{"@type":"Country","name":"RU"},{"@type":"Country","name":"SM"},{"@type":"Country","name":"VA"},{"@type":"Country","name":"UA"},{"@type":"Country","name":"XK"}]}
</script>
```

To make use of this `script` element, create a spider like this one:

```
import scrapy
import json

class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobs'
    start_urls = ["https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote-developer-jobs"]

    def parse(self, response):
        jobs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'job')]")
        # ...

        # visit each job page; OR what you could do: is get the JSON objects (e.g. itemListElement) from the
        # <script type="application/ld+json"> block, and get the direct links from there
        for job in jobs:
            # get the id of the job
            job_id = int(job.xpath('@data-jobid').extract_first())
            job_url = f"https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/{job_id}/"
            yield scrapy.Request(url=job_url, callback=self.parse_job)
        # process pagination below i.e.
        # for link_to_next_page in links_to_next_pages: ...

    def parse_job(self, response):
        job_description = response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').get()
        job_description = json.loads(job_description)
        yield job_description
```

Comment: I tried your solution. I don't get the same contents of the script element `<script type="application/ld+json">`. I get `itemListElement` which contains a list of jobs.

Comment: @Join_Where I updated the script and the comments (with explanations).